# Response from Google is different when using PHP curl vs. curl from command line

Tags: php, curl, google-play-services

I am trying to port https://github.com/simon-weber/gpsoauth to PHP.

When I do a curl request from the command line, the response is as expected:

Command:

`curl "https://android.clients.google.com/auth" --data "Email=<EMAIL>&Passwd=<PASSWD>&service=ac2dm&add_account=1"`

Response:

```
SID=BAD_COOKIE
LSID=BAD_COOKIE
Auth=DQAAABEB....
services=mail,talk,ig,writely,reader...
Email=...
Token=oauth2rt_1/...
GooglePlusUpgrade=0
firstName=...
lastName=...
```

However, when I try the same call from PHP curl, the `Token` is missing.

Code:

```
$data = [
    'Email' => $email,
    'add_account' => 1,
    'Passwd' => $passwd,
    'service' => 'ac2dm',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Response:

```
SID=BAD_COOKIE
LSID=BAD_COOKIE
Auth=DQAAABEB....
services=mail,talk,ig,writely,reader...
Email=...
GooglePlusUpgrade=0
firstName=...
lastName=...
```

I have tried using `file_get_contents` and even `shell_exec`, but the result is the same. Google accepts my credentials but doesn't send a `Token`

Why does PHP Curl behave differently? Do I have to add or remove some header?

Comment: Enable the verbose option (-v and CURLOPT_VERBOSE) and see if there is any difference in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `http_build_query`, it is for query string data, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The `!` should not be encoded when part of a `POST` body. You can pass the array directly as the value for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. See the note about it on http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.

[RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) says:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.

Comment: I get `BadAuthentication` when I use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` no matter if I replace the `@` in my Email address with `%40` or not.
Is there a way to retrieve the actual request sent by `curl`? I have read somewhere here on so that `curl` does not provide an option for that because you provide the body yourself.

btw: I'm on windows with xampp with php 5.6.8 but I also tried on my rpi

Comment: You don't need to encode any data before passing it as the value for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Log or print out your data to make sure it isn't encoded by accident before going in.

Comment: I tried without encoding first, I only tried replacing the `@` by `%40` after that didn't work. I am now using my own "fieldstring builder".

Comment: Try adding this to your curl opts: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`

Comment: Still BadAuthentication.
I have setup a github repo with my code if you want to check:
https://github.com/mgansler/GPSOAuthPHP
It works as it is, but it would be nice to get rid of `encodePostfields()` in line 75

Comment: I think the reason is, that when I pass the array directly to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` the `Content-Type` is changed to `multipart/form-data` which Google doesn't accept. So I will just stick to my solution, thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are missing `EncryptedPasswd` in the payload like the gspoauth python library passes.

Comment: Good catch! I did not know it changed the content type header to multipart

Comment: I works without the `EncryptedPasswd`, maybe I will implement it later. But for now I don't think it is really necessary. It uses HTTPS anyway and if somebody could get hold of an unencrypted Passwd they can access my Google Account. But they could do so as well with just the Token I think.
And for everything else I'm using a different Password anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Paras.

The only difference between the two request was the content length - 80 for curl vs. 82 for PHP.

I have an exclamation mark in my password, which `http_build_query()` replaces with `%21` and `curl` on the command line does not.
Google seems to accept both, but only sends the `Token` if it's a real `!` and not `%21`.